# Python networkx Drawing overlay subgroups in a graph

Tags: python, graph, overlay, networkx, subgraph

I am wondering if it is possible to create a graph using python and possibly networkx,  overlaid subgraphs having different colors? These subgraphs are cluster of nodes.  An example of such graph can be found at:

http://www.barabasilab.com/pubs/CCNR-ALB_Publications/200904-10_PLoSCompBio-HumanPhenotypes/200904-10_PLoSCompBio-Fig2sm.png

Comment: @plaes, One method that I am thinking of is to apply the convex hull finding algorithm to find convex polygons that enclose a set of nodes. I was curious if any method is already available to find the same. Because I do not want to spend couple of days on something that is already available.

Comment: One idea (not sure if possible): Networkx graph -> Shapely (apply convex hull algorithm), convert resulting polygon to outline linestring, then apply parallel offset.